# Map/Satellite menu hidden under map on Android 4 Google Maps

Tags: android, html, google-maps

I have an issue where a normal Google Map loaded on web page (or in a native app) on an Android 4 phone has the Map/Satellite and Street View menu options hidden under the map. It works fine on older Android versions and everywhere else that I can see!

Has anyone else seen this at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a fix for this by adding the following CSS rule:

```
.gmnoprint { -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0); }
```